# size of array in C without sizeof and not in main function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

I want to understand how to know the size of array without using sizeof and not in main function.
and i really want to understand why my code not working when i do it in other function.(in main it works same as sizeof). >>> The rasult i got are some trash numbers

*with char array is understood but i dont know how to do it with other data specifiers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arrSize(int a[],int b[]){
    int size_a = *(&a+1) - a;
    int size_b = *(&b+1) - b;
    printf("%d,%d",size_a,size_b);
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {2,12,14,16};
    int brr[] = {8,53,2,4,16};
    
    arrSize(arr,brr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't know. You need to pass the size as an additional argument to the function.

Comment: In short, you can't. `int []` is literary an array of unknown size. The programmer is responsible to not read outside of the array. By passing another parameter to indicate the size or by other means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding length of array inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590226/finding-length-of-array-inside-a-function) and [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c) (Read past the top answer as well!)

Comment: duplicates: [Finding length of array inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17590226/995714), [How to get array size within function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39429730/995714)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "size of array"? The number of elements or the number of bytes of storage used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function declaration

```
void arrSize(int a[],int b[]){
    int size_a = *(&a+1) - a;
    int size_b = *(&b+1) - b;
    printf("%d,%d",size_a,size_b);
}
```

is adjusted by the compiler to the following declaration

```
void arrSize(int *a,int *b){
    int size_a = *(&a+1) - a;
    int size_b = *(&b+1) - b;
    printf("%d,%d",size_a,size_b);
}
```

That is parameters having array types are adjusted by the compiler to pointers to array element types.

On the other hand, in this call

```
arrSize(arr,brr);
```

the arrays are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

Having a pointer to the first element of an array you are unable to determine the array size pointed to by the pointer.

the initializers in these declarations

```
    int size_a = *(&a+1) - a;
    int size_b = *(&b+1) - b;
```

invoke undefined behavior because you are dereferencing pointers that do not point to valid object.

Comment: I guess you forgot to change square brackets with asterisk in the second version.

Comment: So theres is no way to determine the size of a given array outside the main function?

Comment: @bennyhassan If the array does not have a sentinel value then it is impossible. I do not take into account situations when a pointer to a whole array is passed like for example int a[5]; void f( int ( *p )[5] ); f( &a );